# Monticello - How do I install a package from an online repository (SmalltalkHub) in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, monticello

I can't seem to be able to figure out how to use Monticello with SmalltalkHub. I've used it before to manage local repositories.

Did this:

MCHttpRepository
    location: 'http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/BenComan/PointerDetective/main'
    user: ''
    password: ''

When I opened the Monticello Browser there is no package on the left named PointerDetective.

Do I need to do something extra?

**PS.** Added a package to the left pane myself and then added the repository from the link to it. If I "Open" it I can install just fine and then a new WhateverPackage appears on the left. Then I just delete my old package.

**PS1.** Also noticed that when you first open the Monticello Browser, the online repository does appear in the list on the right, and one can Open it. However selecting something on the left changes the right pane, and you can never get back to it unless you quit Monticello and Open it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in your 1st PS. To add a repo you need to press "+ Repository" select http and paste there "MCHttp…"

[image]

Now on the right side of the inspector you have a dropdown where you select whether you want to see only repos of a selected package or all repos. If you have no package selected you will see all repos anyway (you don't need to reopen browser, you can just deselect package).

Now if you want to associate existing package with a repo, you should either add that repo with having desired package selected, or if the repo is already added, you can right-click it and select "Add to package…"

Comment: Once one selects something from the left pane, how do you get the right pane to display all the repos for everything again?

Comment: @unmircea I've added a screenshot. You have to select "All"

Comment: Ohhh... a big 'aha' moment. The UI could use a redesign :) Thank you!

Comment: @unmircea yes, a lot of things need improvement